# Inspect the locks requested by a out_of_shared_memory query

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

I have an empty parent table that is inherited by hundreds of child tables, all with the same schema. The child tables correspond to file dates that are ingested daily. The tables have an index built on the `time` column (among others) and represent event data. No child table with file date `t` has a row with `time > t`

I'm querying the parent table and getting an out_of_shared_memory error, as the number of locks exceeds my `max_locks_per_transaction` * (`max_connections` + `max_prepared_transactions`) limit.

Is there a way to tell which child tables and associated relations the query wants to lock without running it? Or is it simply all relations that appear in `EXPLAIN ( expr )`? I am restricting `time` to be no older than 30 days, which I thought would reduce the need to lock child tables with file date less than 30 days ago. My query plan, however, demonstrates an index scan being performed on all child tables' `time` index, so I'm wondering if these are indeed locked after the scan (presumably) returns no matching rows.

edit: I should note that I'm running 9.4 via Amazon RDS. I'm aware I can drop old child tables that I don't need anymore or increase max_locks_per_transaction, but wanted to check if there was a way to make my query a bit smarter.

Answer (score 0):

All tables that appear in your query plan will be locked so that they cannot be dropped while the query is in progress, so the large number of tables in your query plan is the cause for the error.

Did you create `CHECK` constraints on the `time` column as shown [in the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-IMPLEMENTATION)? That is required for constraint exclusion to work. Also, the parameter `constraint_exclusion` must not be set to `off`.

For a more exact answer, you'd have to show the table definitions, the query and the execution plan.